# Opening a Google Maps API infowindow from URL parameter (KML layer)

Tags: google-maps-api-3, kml

I have a Google Map that loads a layer of markers from a KML file. Each placemark has an ID (simply id="1" through id="25").

Is it possible to open a specific placemark's infowindow from a URL parameter? If so, how?

The idea is that an address on another page is linked to its corresponding placemark *http://MAPURL.COM/?id=4* or something.

Here's a jsfiddle to see the whole thing in action:
http://jsfiddle.net/natejones/JAyCF/3/

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your customization options are really limited using a KML Overlay.  As far as I know there's no way to open a KML marker's InfoWindow without going through and clicking on the marker; the InfoWindow isn't always loaded in many cases until the KmlLayer's click event is fired.

I'd suggest using native marker elements (google.maps.Marker) which would easily let you trigger an [InfoWindow's](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#InfoWindow) open event.

Comment: Thanks @bamnet. Obviously not what I had hoped to hear, but what I had suspected all along.